# Take 2 variables from a list search in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am working with GeoNames dump file and would like to make a script working. It should:
1) take a row from first txt file, e.g.

Jalalabad, AF

2) Take "Jalalabad" as var1 and "AF" as var2 and use it in search in another txt file which has a line for example:

7053281 Jalālābād   Jalalabad   Bihsud,Jalalabad,Jalālābād,bhswd,jlal abad,بهسود,جلال آباد  34.42189    70.46353    A   ADM2    AF      18  801         0       571 Asia/Kabul  2018-02-13

If found in the 2nd list, I would like to copy whole row (example above) to third file, also in txt. This is my script:

```
myfile ='Geo.txt'
myfile2 = 'allADM.txt'

myfile3 = open('GeoSearch.txt','w',encoding="utf-8")

mylist = []
mylist2 = []


with open(myfile,'r',encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for row in myfile:
        row = row.split(", ")
        var1, var2 = row
        mylist.append(row)

with open(myfile2,'r',encoding='utf-8') as myfile2:
    for row in myfile2:
        row = row.strip()
        mylist2.append(row)

for i in mylist:
    if i[0] in mylist2.row and i[1] in mylist2.row:
            myfile3.write(f"{mylist2.row}\n")
    else:
        pass
```

I get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/python work/GeoNameSearch.py", line 24, in 
    if i[0] in mylist2.row and i[1] in mylist2.row:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'row'

myfile ='Geo.txt' - all the things I want to query

myfile2 = 'allADM.txt' - A massive dump file I want to search in

myfile 3 = output file

Any help appreciated!

EDIT1:
Changed the last part:

```
for i in mylist2:
    if var1 in i and var2 in i:
            myfile3.write(f"{i}\n")
    else:
        pass
```

which resulted in that I got the last result from my search file (12.5k lines). Seems the variables var1 and var2 kept resetting so that it only searched it once.

EDIT2, second script (suggested below + tweaks) also returns empty list:

```
with open('Geo.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as queries:
    search_data = set(queries.readlines())

with open('12.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as dataset:
    data = dataset.readlines()

matching_lines = []

for params in search_data:
    param1, param2 = params.split(', ')

for line in data:
    if param1 in line and param2 in line:
        matching_lines.append(line)


with open('GeoSearch.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as result:
    for res in matching_lines:
        result.write(f'{param1}|{param2}|{res}\n')
```

Comment: Well, the error is pretty straight forward. `myList` and `myList2` do not have an attributte row. For accesssing the "row" is just `myList[i]`

Comment: Thanks

```
for i in mylist2:
    if var1 in i and var2 in i:
            myfile3.write(f"{i}\n")
    else:
        pass
```

Also did not work properly. I got 2 lines quite quick, only the last in the file I searched. It seems the variable search kept resetting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use sets to avoid repetition in your list, also I'm considering performance isn't an issue, otherwise you can open the result file before and write the line on each successful match.

```
with open('Geo.txt') as queries:
  search_data = set(line.strip() for line in queries.readlines())

with open('allADM.txt') as dataset:
  data = [line.strip() for line in dataset.readlines()]

matching_lines = []

for params in search_data:
  param1, param2 = params.split(',')

  for line in data:
    if param1 in line and param2 in line:
      matching_lines.append(line)

with open('GeoSearch.txt', 'w') as result:
  for res in matching_lines:
    result.write(f'{res}\n')
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks for your answer. I just added "r" and encoding for read and its works. I didnt know set method. Yes, the perfomance isnt a factor. It can run whole day for what I care (12,5k lines search out of 4,5 mln lines search). I made it run, and once I see the results and its good I'll select it as a good answer.

Comment: Unfortunately no results. Maybe its due to delimitation of items in the lines (TAB)?

Comment: By no results you mean no matches?

Comment: Exactly, no matches in the newly created file, strangely.

Comment: I thought I got it. The split function should have (space) ", " not ",". Added this code to main post. I even printed param1 and param2 to check and they are good. Files are good as well. Seems there param1 and param2 is not searched at all. Maybe param1 and param2 are not strings hence theyre not found in strings??

Comment: @MichałKraska you can test that easily by reading the file in another shell and seeing the output

Comment: I must have miscopied something from your script. Ran the script again and its working. I will post / approve your answer once I see it worked :) Big thanks!!!

Comment: If the answer satisfied your needs, please approve it :)

Comment: I thought it didnt work. It worked somewhat unpredictably. For example it didnt find Jalalabad from example. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for loop you can use `readlines()`

```
with open(myfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    mylist = myfile.readlines()

# Do same opration with the second one
with open(myfile2, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as myfile2:
    mylist2 = myfile2.readlines()
```

Now `i` contains single string, So you can easily compare the two.

```
for i in mylist:
    if i in mylist2 and i in mylist2:
        myfile3.write(f"{i}\n")
    else:
        pass
```

It much simplify your work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Readlines is very useful but I would like to search via 2 attributes to avoid wrong results.

Comment: Welcome and no problem.